# PySpark task not running on parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster setup with one node and one executor, 8 executor cores. I am trying to use the map feature to do "requests.get" function on parallel. Here is the pseudo code:

```
sc = SparkContext()
url_list = ["a.com", "b.com", "c.com", .....]

def request(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    return page.content

result = sc.parallelize(url_list).map(request).collect()
```

I am expecting the http request to happen on the executor on parallel since i have 8 cores setup in configuration. However, it is requesting on sequence. I get it spark is not really designed for user case like this. But can anyone help me understand why this is not running on parallel based on the core number. Also, how to get what i want which is to run the requests on parallel on spark executor or across different executors.

Comment: What does **sc.parallelize(sc)** mean ? This doesn't make sense. Would you care reviewing your question and adding a Minimum Verifiable and Complete Example please ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sc.parallelize(url_list, 8)`.

Without specifying the number of slices, you may only be getting one partition in the RDD, hence the `map` API may only launch one task to process the partition, hence `request()` will be called in sequence for each row of that partition.

You can check to see how many partitions you have with:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(url_list)  # or with the  ,8)
print rdd.getNumPartitions()
rdd.map(...
```